# How to disable antrun if certain file already exists?

Tags: java, maven, ant, maven-2, maven-antrun-plugin

How can I disable [maven-antrun-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-antrun-plugin/) execution when certain file already exists?:

```
[...]
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.6</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <target>
          <!-- do something really complex in order to create file.txt -->
        </target>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</build>
[...]
```

The execution takes some time and I don't want to repeat it every time when `file.txt` is already there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check for the presence of the file in your **standalone Ant file**. Example:

```
<target name="check-file">
    <available file="foo.bar" property="fileExists" />
</target>

<target name="time-consuming" depends="check-file" unless="fileExists">
    ...
</target>
```

Comment: could you please give a short example here? I tried what is suggested here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133710), but failed to make it working inside Maven.

Comment: @yegor256 Indeed, but I assume you use an external Ant file and your POM calls the `time-consuming` target.

Answer (score 2):

Use a `<profile>` that's only active if `file.txt` doesn't exist:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>createFile</id>
        <activation><file><missing>file.txt</missing></file></activation>
        <build><plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <!-- etc -->
            </plugin>

        </plugins></build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

**Reference:**

- [Introduction to Build Profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)

Comment: There is one problem. When I run `mvn clean test` the file exists during POM initialization, but is destroyed after `clean` phase. Thus, antrun execution is not started, while required... Any thoughts?

Comment: @yegor Sorry, that's how it works. Profiles get evaluated before the build is started and they don't get re-evaluated between goals

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd so you can not run the ant task before the actual profile file exists check is done? i am using antrun to create a file and then checks if it exists in profile. however, the profile is evaluated like you said on the next run because the check is done before clean or install is done.

Comment: @momo I think profiles are evaluated before the build lifecycle is even started, so I doubt you'll have any way to do anything inside a build lifecycle that triggers a specific profile. Maven is just not that type of tool. If you want an imperative build tool, use ant or gradle. Maven is declarative, and trying to work around that usually leads to fear, anger and suffering